# Physical keyboard/mouse on remote PC does not work after Teamviewer

Tags: usb, keyboard, remote-desktop, mouse, teamviewer

I have been using Teamviewer 12 for a long time(6 months or so) to connect to my computer at my office from home. However, I noticed that when I was sitting in front of the PC at my office I cannot type any input with the physical keyboard and the mouse does not work either. On top of that there seems to be two display drivers with the same monitor name and no output is displayed on the screen attached to that PC via HDMI cable.

Teamviewer has been configured properly and there is no issues with remote access and it grants access even after reboot; surprisingly the problem is with access using the peripheral devices physically attached to this PC. The keyboard and mouse gets electricity from USB ports and they work during the system bootup and self test procedures, but when the control is handed over to Windows login manager they fail and do not seem to receive electricity from the ports. I checked the USB ports and they work fine. What may be the cause of this weird behavour and how can I circumvent it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related with missing USB drivers on the computer and it was resolved by reinstallation of USB drivers for the motherboard.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable remote input while being connected.
Check your advanced settings (Access Control):

- Lock the local keyboard and mouse

Comment: I do not have problems with connection and someone interfering with the connection the physical keyboard and mouse attached to that computer just does not work properly.